# Resynchronizing brute-force attack against stream ciphers

Tags: stream-cipher, brute-force-attack

There is a stream cipher without any known cryptographic weaknesses. The attacker knows parts of the key so she can reduce the key-space to a size that can be practically brute-forced.

However the attacker only accesses some (continuous) parts of the ciphertext and she doesn't know how many bits she missed (the attacker is out of sync). She does know the general structure of the underlying plaintext and can check if a part of the keystream decrypts a partial ciphertext correctly. The attacker can also match known ciphertext-plaintext pairs, so parts of the keystream is also known to her.

There are no encrypting or decrypting oracles to use.

My understanding is that the attacker should generate a (theoretically) infinite long keystream and check if any parts match the ciphertext parts for every key candidate. This is of course impractical even for a couple of possible keys.

Is there a practical strategy for the attacker to brute-force the correct key *and* "synchronize" with the cipher stream?

What kind of cryptographic weakness of the cipher would make the task easier?

**EDITED:** Added some clarifications based on the comments of @fgrieu.

Comment: Is the stream cipher in the question strictly exclusive-OR of plaintext with a single large keystream (or is it a more complex protocol)? $\;$ Also: can the attacker mount a chosen-plaintext attack? If yes, hint: do this with a plaintext that does not require re-synchronization.

Comment: The keystream is simply XORd. The attacker can't mount CPA.

Comment: Can we liberally interpret "_know the general structure of the underlying plaintext_" into _all plaintext bytes have high bit clear_? If yes, hint: that's choosen-enough plaintext. $\;$ If no, please clarify what the quote allows.

Comment: The attacker knows pairs of ciphertext-plaintext "blocks" (parts of the stream) and thus the matching parts of the keystream too, but she can't use an encrypting oracle.

Comment: Ah, so that attacker knows **synchronized** ciphertext-plaintext pairs, thus some of the true keystream. Is there anything problematic with just _searching_ the chronologically first such known keystream segment in each candidate keystream corresponding to candidate keys, and in those few where it appears soon enough, computing more candidate keystream and search the other known keystream segments, in order to confirm the candidate key?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was thinking about. The problem is that searching through long keystreams can increase the cost of the attack significantly especially if large parts of the stream was missed and the keyspace is also big.

Comment: Searching the first 32-bit or 64-bit segment of known keystream into the candidate keystream while it is generated can be done at very little cost, if that's engineered into the software (or hardware) generating the candidate keystream; the rest of the search is more costly, but rare, thus has little impact on performance.

Comment: The attacker can't expect that only a few words are missed. I ran some quick benchmarks: In synced state I can do ~180000 tries/s. If I have to search through the first 100k of the keystream speed drops to ~3000 t/s.